# DirectoryEntry instance are not disposed in LDAP

Tags: ldap, netstat, directoryentry, directorysearcher

I'm not sure if that is the expected behavior, but I would expect it to act differently.

After running the following code

```cs
using (var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
    directoryPath,
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ldapUsername"],
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ldapPassword"],
    AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous))
{
    // ldap query
}
```

When the query is executed and, as I would expect, I could see an active session on the LDAP.

Run the following command on the LDAP machine:

```
netstat -nat | findstr my_ip_address | findstr :389
```

I could see an active session on the LDAP:

```
TCP ldap_ip_address:389 my_ip_address:24730 ESTABLISHED InHost
```

But when we get out from the `using` section and the `DirectoryEntry` / `DirectorySearcher` are disposed, I would expect the session to be closed.
Still when I run the netstat command again, I could see the same active session.

Is there any reason why the session is not disposed in the LDAP? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 0):

One of two things could be happening.

1. The connection is actually closed. The second time you run netstat, if the connection state shows `CLOSE_WAIT` or `TIME_WAIT` instead of `ESTABLISHED`, then this is the case: the connection was indeed closed. The connection is held in that state for a time in case some packets for that connection arrive late.
2. `DirectoryEntry` is a wrapper around the native [Windows Active Directory Services Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_adsi/) (ADSI). That has some per-process [connection caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/connection-caching) built in. So if you have another non-disposed `DirectoryEntry` in your application that uses the same connection, then disposing a second `DirectoryEntry` will not close that connection. The connection stays open as long as there is at least one non-disposed `DirectoryEntry` in your application.

Comment: i've tried to excluded any non-disposed DirectoryEntry in my application. and created an application with a single execution of DirectoryEntry. and it gave me the same result . in addition the state of the connection remains ESTABLISHED till my application is closed and only then it is removed

Comment: If the connection goes away when the application is closed, then it's definitely connection caching. But I can't replicate this myself. If I create a console app that has one `DirectoryEntry` inside a `using`, then pauses after the `using`, I see the connection disconnect when I monitor it using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). But if I keep a second `DirectoryEntry` outside the `using`, the connection stays open.